# multiple responsive Image fit into single div with css

Tags: html, css

[image]
I want to create this type of structure with images. I'm using bootstrap, is it possible to create this type of layout with bootstrap,if not then how?

here is the sample code:

```css
.side_padding { padding-left: 2.5%; padding-right: 2.5%; }
.img_holder { object-fit: fill; width: 90%; }
```

```html
        <div class="selection"> 
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row side_padding">
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <div class="img_holder banner"><img src="images/img1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></div>
                        <div class="img_holder banner"><img src="images/img2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3 center-block">
                        <div class="img_holder banner"><img src="images/img3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></div>
                        <div class="img_holder banner"><img src="images/img4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="img_holder banner"><img src="images/img5.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></div>
                        <div class="img_holder banner"><img src="images/img6.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></div>
                        <div class="img_holder banner"><img src="images/img7.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What is the question exactly ? you already have created the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the example is a basic 3 column layout with images. If you want a perfect square then you need fixed aspect ratios for each image (or more accurately containers that will "crop" them using overflow:hidden).

If height not being even isn't an issue then you should be able to just do something like (jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/1axajum5/) - all you need to do is vertical spacing with margin on the images or padding/margin on the rows however I've omitted this to keep things focused on the layout as tweaking the padding is trivial once the layout has been implemented:

```
<div class="selection"> 
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row side_padding">
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <div class="row"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" class="col-sm-12" alt=""/></div>
                    <div class="row"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" class="col-sm-12" alt=""/></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 center-block">
                    <div class="row"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" class="col-sm-12" alt=""/></div>
                    <div class="row"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" class="col-sm-12" alt=""/></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="row"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" class="col-sm-12" alt=""/></div>
                    <div class="row"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" class="col-sm-12" alt=""/></div>
                    <div class="row"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" class="col-sm-12" alt=""/></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Essentially you can nest columns as needed BUT columns apply a negative margin to compensate for padding applied on the row so if nesting columns (almost) always wrap them in a row.

Comment: thank you...but what if image size change like this... https://jsfiddle.net/1axajum5/3/

Comment: As we've applied col-sm-12 to the images this will apply width: 100% to them and will cause them to scale responsively maintaining aspect ratio. The narrower images are they higher they'll become, the wider they are the shorter they'll become. A fixed height solution becomes much more complicated quickly. Usually grid layouts like this need to be constrained either via height or width to avoid cropping either that or you need to know the aspect ratio of images and set some guidelines to ensure they fit.

Comment: Sorry I missed the desired layout image. If you know what images are going in you can precrop them and/or wrap the images in fixed height containers. If the images may change you'll need to either use a server side language such as PHP or script it client side using javascript to solve this both of these solutions will perform some cropping. I recommend avoiding the "perfect box" if possible. It's best to constrain either height or width - constraining on both can get messy fast.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow as per share demo with you

```css
#photos {
  /* Prevent vertical gaps */
  line-height: 0;
   
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  -webkit-column-gap:   15px;
  -moz-column-count:    5;
  -moz-column-gap:      0px;
  column-count:         5;
  column-gap:           0px;  
}

#photos img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  margin:10px;
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count:         4;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count:         3;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count:         3;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    1;
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  column-count:         1;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="photos"><img alt="pretty kitty" src="https://placekitten.com/358/270"><img alt="pretty kitty" src="https://placekitten.com/378/282"><img alt="pretty kitty" src="https://placekitten.com/242/249"><img alt="pretty kitty" src="https://placekitten.com/294/292"><img alt="pretty kitty" src="https://placekitten.com/258/246"><img alt="pretty kitty" src="https://placekitten.com/360/244"><img alt="pretty kitty" src="https://placekitten.com/300/225"><img alt="pretty kitty" src="https://placekitten.com/254/274"><img alt="pretty kitty" src="https://placekitten.com/384/269"><img alt="pretty kitty" src="https://placekitten.com/278/249"><img alt="pretty kitty" src="https://placekitten.com/290/251"><img alt="pretty kitty" src="https://placekitten.com/391/259"><img alt="pretty kitty" src="https://placekitten.com/335/393"><img alt="pretty kitty" src="https://placekitten.com/363/225"><img alt="pretty kitty" src="https://placekitten.com/277/225"><img alt="pretty kitty" src="https://placekitten.com/263/359"><img alt="pretty kitty" src="https://placekitten.com/249/259"><img alt="pretty kitty" src="https://placekitten.com/346/315"><img alt="pretty kitty" src="https://placekitten.com/310/306"></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Gridster js for this.

http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/